# Convert UTC time ONLY to local time ONLY (without date) using javascript or momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am fetching a string from database which is in a 24hr format and is stored in UTC time. For example "18:00:00". I would want this time to be converted into local time only (no date is required), wherever the time zone may be and display it in 12hr format. For example, if the timezone is Australian Eastern Standard Time, I have to find out the time difference which is 11 hrs ahead of UTC time and display it as "05:00 AM" and also do the vice versa of local time only into UTC time only (no date is required) so that I can save it back to database. I have searched a lot for it but everyone mentions about converting date object from UTC to local or vice versa but not for time only. Please help me out with this.

Comment: What is you input? How you are getting date value from db?

Comment: In db the Data Type is "time(0)". So when I fetch it from db, it is a string in the UI. I am using SQL Server db and .NET in the backend and Angular in the frontend

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```js
let utcTime = "18:00:00";
let utcText = moment(utcTime,'HH:mm').format("HH:mm");

let local = moment.utc(utcTime,'HH:mm').local().format("hh:mm A");

let localTime = local;//setting local time
let utc = moment(localTime,'hh:mm A').utc().format("HH:mm");

$("#utc").html(utcText + " (UTC Time)");
$("#local").html(local + " (Local Time)");
$("#utc1").html(localTime + " (Local Time1)");
$("#local1").html(utc + " (UTC Time1)");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.2/moment.js"></script>
<div id="utc"></div>
<div id="local"></div>
<div id="utc1"></div>
<div id="local1"></div>
```

Create a moment object using time and type , then convert to [local](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/) timezone using `local()`

Comment: It works but is there a way to get it in 12hr format? For example if the UTC string is "05:00:00", then the local time obtained is "16:00 PM". Is there a way to get it as "04:00 PM"? I can split the string and check if hrs is greater than 12 but if there is an easier way using moment, it would be a cleaner solution. I would also like it to be converted back to UTC 24hr string after user edits it in the UI.

Comment: Yup. It works like a charm! Thank you so much. Is there a way to achieve the opposite as well? For example from "05:00 AM" local time to "18:00:00" UTC time. I am providing the user an option to edit the time in the UI and so I have to save it back to db in 24hr UTC string

Comment: @suvenk check again

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot for the quick response :)

Comment: @suvenk upvote and mark if it works, Happy coding ;)

Comment: Neat, I'm wondering is there a way to do this without moment.js, in vanilla js.